# C program output is confusing

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define PROD(x) (x*x)
void main()
{
clrscr();
int p=3,k;
k=PROD(p+1); //here i think value 3+1=4 would be passed to macro
printf("\n%d",k);
getch();
}
```

In my opinion, the output should be `16`, but I get `7`.

Can anyone please tell me why?

Comment: Schoolbook example of where C macros go wrong :)  Use functions instead.

Comment: Isn't this the *first* thing they warn about in any C programming book?  Whatever you use, I'm sure you can find a better one.

Comment: Urgh, a `void main()`...

Comment: "In my opinion" ... opinions aren't relevant, language standards are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preprocessor expands PROD(p+1) as follows:

```
k = (p+1*p+1);
```

With p=3, this gives: 3+1*3+1 = 7.

You should have written your #define as follows:

```
#define PROD(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Answer (score 21):

Macros are *expanded*, they don't have values *passed* to them. Have look what your macro expands to in the statement that assigns to `k`.

```
k=(p+1*p+1);
```

Prefer functions to macros, if you have to use a macro the minimum you should do is to fully parenthesise the parameters. Note that even this has potential surprises if users use it with expressions that have side effects.

```
#define PROD(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that PROD is a macro and will not behave exactly like you intend it to. Hence, it will look like this:

```
k = p+1*p+1
```

Which of course means you have:

```
k = 3+1*3+1 = 7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#define PROD(x) (x*x)
```

`PROD(3+1)` is changed by the preprocessor to `3+1*3+1`

Answer (score 2):

macro are not function . These are replaced by name

It will be `p+1*p+1`

Answer (score 2):

This is what compiler is going to see after preprocessors does its job: k= p+1*p+1. When p =  3, this is evaluated as k = 3+(1*3)+1. Hence 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why you should use functions instead of macros. A function only evaluates each parameter once. Why not try

int prod(int x)
{ return x * x; }

and see the difference!